# Is there a way to create React Native Picker that works for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, picker

i want something like the native datetimepicker for android and ios that I can customize with text instead of date or time. Is there a possiblity to do this?

So something like this in the image but instead with own customized text. I only found a community react native picker as the normal react native picker is deprecated. But it only works on Android as dropdown.

[image]